# Using a JSON store like myjson with react redux

Tags: json, reactjs, redux

We have a react redux application, which is currently not having a storage mechanism. And i am prototyper, not much of a developer.

I would like to commit the code to a JSON store like myjson.com with the click on a button on the UI.

This is only for testing before we go to a full fledged solution.

Any guidance would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure we are on the same page but you can uae jsonserver,you can store any data you want in it,i hope this will helpful

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using firestore, it was not as easy as click of a button, but served my purpose.